# Add project files from Local machine to Github Repository

Tags: ios, github, repository, branch

I am working on an iOS project. our employee has created a repository say app and we have a master branch by default. employee has created another branch say "second" now I need to upload my project files from my machine to Github repository's Branch "Second" looking into a lot of tutorial and didn't understood what and how to do that... This question may have already asked but sorry didn't helped any...

Comment: `git clone <url> --branch <branch> --single-branch [<folder>]` to clone a specific branch and then modify and commit as you would normally do, changes will only exist on the branch you cloned. documentation: http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: can you describe it better, if the branch "second" was created from your master branch then you just need to merge the "master" into "second".

Comment: @Krzysztof I really Don't know much about these operations. it's my first approach with Github. but when I asked my employee he said it was created from master

Comment: @Joker if i understand correctly then you just need to switch to the branch your client created and merge all your changes. But Are you sure it's not new repository? Would be worth if you did some quick git tutorials first. And there are some nice gui clients too like source tree which might be help to you.

Comment: @Krzysztof yup it's not a Repository it's a branch.

Comment: @Joker best will be to ask employee who created other branch for help

Comment: @Krzysztof The employee itself created everything...

Answer (score 0):

At first, make full backup of your project, so 
you can restore it if something goes wrong.

If you have local git repository (in terminal you can see .git and .git**** files after execute "ls -la" command in project directory):

```
1) Open your project folder with your local git repository in Terminal and add your Github repository as origin:
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/your_user/your_repo.git 
(This url you can see at Github repo) 

2) Push all your local branches onto repository:
$ git push --all origin
```

If you do not have local git repository:

```
1) Create new folder, go inside it and in Terminal execute this:
$ git clone https://github.com/your_user/your_repo.git

2) Copy all your iOS project (with inner files/folders/etc) into that folder

3) Add all your local files into local git repo:
$ git add .

4) Commit all changes:
$ git commit -m initial    

5) Push all your local branches onto repository:
$ git push --all origin

Also see Github help: 
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote/
https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/
```